# The requested module '' does not provide an export named 'default' JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, export, syntax-error

New programmer here. I am trying to replicate a youtube video for a program that creates a CSV table viewer on html and am getting this error
SyntaxError: The requested module './TableCsv.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

I have tried adding curly braces around TableCsv in main.js but no luck. When I try adding my own export in TableCsv.js it says A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528).

Here is my code

main.js

```
import TableCsv from "./TableCsv.js";

const tableRoot = document.querySelector("#csvRoot");
const csvFileInput = document.querySelector("#csvFileInput");
const tableCsv = new TableCsv(tableRoot);

csvFileInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    Papa.parse(csvFileInput.files[0], {
        delimiter: ",",
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        complete: results => {
            tableCsv.update(results.data.slice(1), results.data[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

TableCsv.js

```
class TableCsv {
    /**
     * @param {HTMLTableElement} root The table element which will display the CSV data.
     */
    constructor(root) {
      this.root = root;
    }

    /**
     * Clears existing data in the table and replaces it with new data.
     *
     * @param {string[][]} data A 2D array of data to be used as the table body
     * @param {string[]} headerColumns List of headings to be used
     */
    update(data, headerColumns = []) {
      this.clear();
      this.setHeader(headerColumns);
      this.setBody(data);
    }
  
    /**
     * Clears all contents of the table (incl. the header).
     */
    clear() {
      this.root.innerHTML = "";
    }
  
    /**
     * Sets the table header.
     *
     * @param {string[]} headerColumns List of headings to be used
     */
    setHeader(headerColumns) {
      this.root.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterbegin",
        `
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      ${headerColumns.map((text) => `<th>${text}</th>`).join("")}
                  </tr>
              </thead>
          `
      );
    }
  
    /**
     * Sets the table body.
     *
     * @param {string[][]} data A 2D array of data to be used as the table body
     */
    setBody(data) {
      const rowsHtml = data.map((row) => {
        return `
                  <tr>
                      ${row.map((text) => `<td>${text}</td>`).join("")}
                  </tr>
              `;
      });
  
      this.root.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `
              <tbody>
                  ${rowsHtml.join("")}
              </tbody>
          `
      );
    }
  }
  
  const tableRoot = document.querySelector("#csvRoot");
  const csvFileInput = document.querySelector("#csvFileInput");
  const tableCsv = new TableCsv(tableRoot);
  
  csvFileInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    Papa.parse(csvFileInput.files[0], {
      delimiter: ",",
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: (results) => {
        tableCsv.update(results.data.slice(1), results.data[0]);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the file `TableCsv.js` you are not making your object available for external files to use. The way that this is done is via the `export` statement. You can either export something (or several somethings) as named exports, so that you would need to import them with a statement like `import { Thing } from 'module'`, or you can make a default export (which seems to be the case here) where the import statement then looks as follows: `import Thing from 'module'`.

To export your object in `TableCsv.js` add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```js
export default TableCsv
```

Alternatively, change the line where you define the variable to be as follows:

```js
export default class TableCsv {
```

Answer (score 13):

To address `A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)`, you cannot have multiple default exports, since 1 module can have at most 1 default export. You are using the default export in:

```
import TableCsv from "./TableCsv.js"; // import the default export as TableCsv
```

vs

```
import { TableCsv } from "./TableCsv.js"; // import the specific exported symbol 'TableCsv'
                                          // from the file "./TableCsv.js"
```

Try adding export in front of the TableCsv class, i.e:
`export class TableCsv {`

Answer (score 2):

While using the import statement the exported modules should be exported as

```
export default className/functionName;
```

Where as while using the old require statements the exported modules should be exported as

```
module.exports = className/functionName;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the file TableCsv.js

```js
// TableCSV.js

import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();
/*    
    your code
*/
export default router;
```

Then for it to work in the main.js

```js
// main.js

import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import tableCsv from './TableCsv.js';

/*    
    your code
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

import {TableCsv} from "./TableCsv.js"
you forgot '{}'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).